# How to play HDR with windows 11 on my Laptop?

Tags: hdmi, windows-11, external-display, displayport, hdr

I have a laptop, MSI 63M 7REX. I am not able to use HDR capabilities in Windows 11 OS.

I have MSI laptop, model 62M 7REX. It has Nvidia GTX 1050ti. It has a minidisplay port (I don't know which version. Not mentioned on their official website.)

Monitor: LG ultragear 27GN950

For **native laptop display** it shows the following.

**Play streaming HDR video: Supported

Use HDR: Not supported**

I bought a [monitor](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08K4MZMZN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which supports VESA HDR 600.

I bought a mini display port to display port [cable](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B09VYXM1QC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

but for **LG Ultragear** display the HDR section of windows shows:

**Play streaming HDR video: Not supported

Use HDR: Not supported**

(Same problem even with HDMI cable which support HDR with PS4)

(This problem is with all resolutions I checked.)

I am only getting 4K 60Hz and no HDR with mini display port and 4K 30Hz and no HDR with HDMI. I understand that is the limit of the ports, but **why** there is **no HDR**, I am not able to figure out.

I searched internet for Nvidia GTX 1050ti and found the following:

[Nvidia 1050ti supports HDR](https://www.avsforum.com/threads/gtx-1050ti-do-4k-hdr.3044196/#:%7E:text=Yes.%20It%20does%204K%20HDR%2C%20even%20at%2060,use%20madVR%20and%20MPC-BE%20which%20gives%20excellent%20results.)

Comment: It's really difficult to do research, your links to Amazon are not functional, but you don't provide specific model information for your monitor. From what I can gleam from my research, your mobile GPU, simply does NOT support HDR10.  [`HDR 600`](https://displayhdr.org/general/not-all-hdr-is-created-equal/) is actually an undefined specification. It appears that `HDR 600` just refers to the lamination brightness of the display.